# Calculating field if it's empty

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula

I have a calculated field containing "`RemainingWork`". The calculation in this field is based on two other fields, "`Estimate`" and "`RegisteredHours`".

If "`RemainingWork`" has not been set, it's supposed to calculate its value from `"Estimate" - "RegistereHours"`, if any.

I'm a SharePoint newbie so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Below is what I've tried, but it fails horribly.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([RemainingWork]),"",([Estimate]-[RegisteredHours]))
```

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax is:

```
 =IF( condition , TRUE , FALSE )
```

So your Formula should be:

```
 =IF( ISBLANK([RemainingWork]) , [Estimate]-[RegisteredHours] , "" )
```

Since there are no spaces in the names you can also write:

```
 =IF( ISBLANK(RemainingWork) , Estimate-RegisteredHours , "" )
```

On a non-english locale it could be you need **;** (semi-colons) (like Excel)

```
 =IF( ISBLANK(RemainingWork) ; Estimate-RegisteredHours ; "" )
```

---

#### Documentation and examples of all SharePoint Functions:

### [www.viewmaster365.com/functions](http://www.viewmaster365.com/functions)

Comment: Thanks for the input and thanks for the link! That's sure to be useful.